# SELECT Top values for each records

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have been battling through this query/query design for sometime now and I thought it's time to ask the experts! Here's my table results:

```
ID   | Status       | date         |
---------------------------------
05   | Returned     | 20/6/2018    |
03   | Sent         | 12/5/2018    |
01   | Pending      | 07/6/2018    |
01   | Engaged      | 11/4/2018    |
03   | Contacted    | 16/4/2018    |
05   | Surveyed     | 04/3/2017    |
05   | No Contact   | 05/3/2017    |
```

**How do I get it to return top/newest value for each ID:**

```
ID   | Status       | date         |
---------------------------------
05   | Returned     | 20/6/2018    |
03   | Sent         | 12/5/2018    |
01   | Pending      | 07/6/2018    |
```

**I've tried group by, TOP 1, Distinct and results still not what I wanted. Also, displaying the results by top 5% is won't do either as the ID can be more than just 3 types.**

My QUERY below:

```
INSERT INTO TmpAllcomsEmployee ( StatusID, EmployeeID, CommunicationDate )
SELECT DISTINCT CommunicationLog.StatusID, TmpAllcomsEmployee.EmployeeID, 
Max(CommunicationLog.CommunicationDate) AS MaxOfCommunicationDate
FROM CommunicationLog RIGHT JOIN TmpAllcomsEmployee ON 
     CommunicationLog.EmployeeID = TmpAllcomsEmployee.EmployeeID
GROUP BY CommunicationLog.StatusID, TmpAllcomsEmployee.EmployeeID
ORDER BY Max(CommunicationLog.CommunicationDate) DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select cl.*
from CommunicationLog as cl
where cl.date = (select max(cl2.date)
                 from CommunicationLog as cl2
                 where cl2.EmployeeID = cl.EmployeeID
                );
```

This gets the most recent record for each employee in `CommunicationLog`.  You can join in the other table if you really need it.  It does not seem unnecessary unless you are using it for filtering.

Comment: @aaendewy . . . That's pretty vague and provide no information to help you.